# Send an array of complex objects using ksoap2 to .NET web service

Tags: .net, web-services, java-me, ksoap2

I am facing a problem in sending an array of complex object from a J2ME Client using KSOAP to .net web service (Soap services).

my TestSoap.java file has a setArr() method which takes an array of PropHeaderMapBin object and sends it to the web service which returns an integer (count of PropHeaderMapBin objects)

```
TestSoap.java

package org.tempuri;

    import com.n9ciphers.test.Constants;
    import java.util.Vector;
    import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransport;
    import org.tempuri.PropHeaderMapBin;

    public final class TestSoap {

        public int setArr(PropHeaderMapBin[] inArr) throws Exception {

            SoapObject _client = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/", "SetArr");
            SoapObject[] _propHeaderMapBinSO = new SoapObject[inArr.length];

            PropHeaderMapBin[] prop = inArr;
            //PropHeaderMapBin[] prop = new PropHeaderMapBin[inArr.length];
            Vector _propVector = new Vector(inArr.length);
            if (inArr != null) {

                //System.out.println("_len  " + inArr.length );

                for (int i = 0; i < inArr.length; i++) {
                    _propHeaderMapBinSO[i] = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/", "PropHeaderMapBin");
                    _propHeaderMapBinSO[i].addProperty("PropertyName", prop[i].getPropertyName());
                    _propHeaderMapBinSO[i].addProperty("value", prop[i].getValue());
                    _propHeaderMapBinSO[i].addProperty("HeaderText", prop[i].getHeaderText());
                    _propHeaderMapBinSO[i].addProperty("label", prop[i].getLabel());

                    _propVector.addElement(_propHeaderMapBinSO[i]);
                }
            }

            _client.addProperty(pi, _propVector);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope _envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            _envelope.addMapping("http://www.tempuri.org/", "PropHeaderMapBin", new PropHeaderMapBin().getClass());
            //_envelope.addTemplate (_client);
            _envelope.bodyOut = _client;
            _envelope.dotNet = true;

            HttpTransport _ht = new HttpTransport(Constants.endPoint + "Test.asmx");
            _ht.debug = true;
            _ht.call("http://tempuri.org/SetArr", _envelope);

            //System.out.println("response: " + result.toString());

            System.out.println("Request Dump:" + _ht.requestDump);
            //Dialog.show("Request Dump", _ht.requestDump, Dialog.TYPE_INFO, null, "OK", null);
            System.out.println("Response Dump:" + _ht.responseDump);
            //Dialog.show("Response Dump", _ht.responseDump, Dialog.TYPE_INFO, null, "OK", null);

            return Integer.parseInt(_envelope.getResponse().toString());
            //return 0;
        }
    }
```

Output of setArr() method call. the server does not recognize the datatype of the objects in array and it sets the arraytype to anytype[3] and returns a 0 instead of 3.

```
Request Dump:
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <v:Header />
    <v:Body>
        <SetArr xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" id="o0" c:root="1">
            <inArr i:type="c:Array" c:arrayType="d:anyType[3]">
                <item i:type="n0:PropHeaderMapBin" xmlns:n0="http://tempuri.org/">
                    <PropertyName i:type="d:string">1</PropertyName>
                    <value i:type="d:string">1</value>
                    <HeaderText i:type="d:string">Pradhan</HeaderText>
                    <label i:type="d:string">Pradhan</label>
                </item>
                <item i:type="n1:PropHeaderMapBin" xmlns:n1="http://tempuri.org/">
                    <PropertyName i:type="d:string">2</PropertyName>
                    <value i:type="d:string">2</value>
                    <HeaderText i:type="d:string">Kavya</HeaderText>
                    <label i:type="d:string">Kavya</label>
                </item>
                <item i:type="n2:PropHeaderMapBin" xmlns:n2="http://tempuri.org/">
                    <PropertyName i:type="d:string">3</PropertyName>
                    <value i:type="d:string">3</value>
                    <HeaderText i:type="d:string">Puchi</HeaderText>
                    <label i:type="d:string">Puchi</label>
                </item>
            </inArr>
        </SetArr>
    </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>


Response Dump:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <SetArrResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <SetArrResult>0</SetArrResult>
        </SetArrResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
response = 0
```

my wsdl file for reference

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
            <s:element name="GetArr">
                <s:complexType/>
            </s:element>
            <s:element name="GetArrResponse">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetArrResult" type="tns:ArrayOfPropHeaderMapBin"/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:complexType name="ArrayOfPropHeaderMapBin">
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="PropHeaderMapBin" nillable="true" type="tns:PropHeaderMapBin"/>
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
            <s:complexType name="PropHeaderMapBin">
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PropertyName" type="s:string"/>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="value" type="s:string"/>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="HeaderText" type="s:string"/>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="label" type="s:string"/>
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
            <s:element name="SetArr">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="inArr" type="tns:ArrayOfPropHeaderMapBin"/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:element name="SetArrResponse">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SetArrResult" type="s:int"/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
        </s:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="GetArrSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetArr"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetArrSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetArrResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="SetArrSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SetArr"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="SetArrSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SetArrResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="TestSoap">
        <wsdl:operation name="GetArr">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:GetArrSoapIn"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:GetArrSoapOut"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="SetArr">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:SetArrSoapIn"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:SetArrSoapOut"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="TestSoap" type="tns:TestSoap">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="HelloWorld">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetArr">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/GetArr" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="SetArr">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/SetArr" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="TestSoap12" type="tns:TestSoap">
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetArr">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/GetArr" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="SetArr">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/SetArr" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="Test">
        <wsdl:port name="TestSoap" binding="tns:TestSoap">
            <soap:address location="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Services/Test.asmx"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="TestSoap12" binding="tns:TestSoap12">
            <soap12:address location="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Services/Test.asmx"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I wud appreciate any help if some one has already faced this kind of issue and resolved it successfully.

Comment: user435696: Did you find a solution to this problem?  I have the same issue.  Your info above helped me a lot.

Comment: what was the solution to this? i tried the soapUI but cant seem to spot any big difference between the ksoap2 and s soapUI requests

Answer (score 1):

I can give you hint to solve a problem.

using soapUI tool create web service project with same WSDL (it is very easy and fast).

Compare your request dump with soap body generated by soapUI. You will find out the difference and

hence solution.

Answer (score 0):

@Rajnikant had it spot on. if you have wcf web services that are not working, use SOAPui to import the wsdl endpoints. this will create a test harness for the methods that you can then use to call your wcf methods and see the request dump. Compare this with the request dump from the mobile (using androidHttpTransport.requestDump).....note the parameters being passed and their namespaces....this is very important